# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 121 Current browser version is 120.0.6099.227

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from otp import get_otp

import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
webdriver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
webdriver_service.start()
driver = uc.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
```

there is such a code. After 10 launches, I started getting this error -

*selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:54585
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 121
Current browser version is 120.0.6099.227*

Any thoughts pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently with `undetected-chromedriver`, you would need to update the `version_main` arg of `uc.Chrome()` every time a new version of Chrome comes out. That's not self-sustaining. Alternatively, there's https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase with UC Mode, which is basically `undetected-chromedriver` with some improvements, such as automatically getting a version of chromedriver that is compatible with your version of Chrome. Set `uc=True` to activate UC Mode in a SeleniumBase script. Here's an example:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
```

There's some documentation about it here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/2213

Here's a larger script:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
# DO MORE STUFF
driver.quit()
```

For customizing the reconnect time when loading a URL that has bot detection services, you could swap the `get()` line with something like this:

```py
driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax", reconnect_time=5)
```

(The `reconnect_time` is the wait time before chromedriver reconnects with Chrome. Before the time is up, a website cannot detect Selenium, but it also means that Selenium can't yet issue commands to Chrome.)

Comment: Thank you! I will use it! As I understand it, the methods are different?

Comment: SeleniumBase adds more methods to the original Selenium driver.

Answer (score 2):

fixed by adding version_main=120

```
webdriver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
webdriver_service.start()
driver = uc.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options, version_main=120)
```